# Sharepoint 2013 : Survey Partial Response : Continue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, survey, survey-list

I have created a survey in SharePoint 2013 and the users are able to respond to the survey.

However, in case the user saves a partial survey the user has to Navigate to View All Response and Edit the response to continue the survey.

Is there a way where the **Respond to Survey** recognizes the partial response and directly edits the survey?

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to navigation to edit a response and edit it.

As a workaround, you can create a SharePoint Designer workflow and send an mail with the edit link to the submitter. Then the submitter could edit the response directly via the link.

Steps for your reference:
1. Edit a response and copy the address link.
  The link should be like:
  https://sitename/Lists/surveylist/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsitename%2FLists%2Fsurveylist%2FAllItems%2Easpx
2. Create a SharePoint Designer workflow for your survey list.
3. Insert "Send an Email" action into it.
4. Edit the action, set "To" to Created By:
[image]
5. Set Subject and body as your requirement. 
6. select the area that you want to put the link and set the link as:

[image]

Note: The URL in the String Builder is the copied link in the step1. You need to change "ID=xx" to "CurrentItem:ID".
7. Set the workflow automatically start when an item is created.
8. Publish the workflow

The email that submitter received is like:
[image]

Please have a try and let's know the result.